# Netflix Zuul on one port and Hystrix Dashboard on another

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-zuul, hystrix, spring-boot-actuator, spring-cloud-netflix

I am using Netflix Zuul with Spring Boot for routing/proxy purposes. It listens on a port defined in a `application.yml`:

```
server:
  port: ${port:8080}
```

I also wanted to use Hystrix for circuit breaking as well as having the Hystrix dashboard. I achieved that with the annotation as follow:

```
@EnableHystrixDashboard
@SpringBootApplication
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpringApplication(Main.class).run(args);
    }
}
```

Now I can access the dashboard under `localhost:8080/hystrix`.
Additionaly I have Spring Actuator under port `8181` set with `management.port: 8181` property in `application.yml`.

My question is:

- is that possible to have hystrix dashboard located under other port, e.g. 8181 or any other? So I can be sure that port `8080` is dedicated only for routing/proxy purposes?

Comment: just add the server.port property in hystrix dashboard's application.yml. it will start in other port what the actuall problem .

Comment: The Hystirx Dashboard is enabled in the same application as my Zuul, so changing the port makes Zuul listening on different port, not only Hystirx Dashboard

Comment: why would you do that ... if you need diff port i think hystrix dashboard will have to be a seperate application... Having it on the same project might complicate things....

Comment: Actually I did it this way at the moment, I was curious whether is it possible to have as one app. However, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you run both things under the same application they will always have the same port because both things run in the same embedded server which is what is configured by using the property:

`server:
  port: 8080`